# How to compare each element with every other in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

The problem is, for an IEnumerable of rectangles I need to know for each rectangle whether it intersects any of the others. So the output would be a sequence with the same count containing one boolean value for every rectangle.

So it is kind of a nested loop problem but it should not compare the element with itself and if rect A intersects rect B there is no need to check rect B again.

Is this possible with LINQ?

Comment: whats the criteria for intersection?

Comment: `listOfRectangles.Where(r => r != [specifyRectangle]).Select(r => intersectionConditions);` However, this will still count duplicates if already found.

Comment: @austinwernli It sounds like thalm wants to cut down on the number of checks by, for example, checking only *one* of [A and B] and [B and A]. Your little snippet there will check every rectangle against every other, which is twice the work.

Comment: Yeah, i gotcha now heh. Was throwing a base implementation out there :)

Comment: Do the elements have some kind of id? If so you can check if a.id > b.id

Comment: @Jashaszun yes exactly, but it might not be possible with LINQ...?

Comment: @Luc thats a key problem... rect != rect checks for difference in properties but does not check whether its actually the same element in regard to the index... so i guess it has to be nested for loops then to work with indices.

Comment: You could extend the rectangle class with a guid, then string compare these guides and only process of rectangle a's good is smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//for every rectangle in your list. 
//search the list, eliminating the same one, 
//and find if any of the others intersect with it.
var intersectingRectangles = rectangles
  .Where(rect => rectangles
                 .Where(r => r != rect)
                 .Any(r => DoIntersect(rect, r)));
```

This assumes that you have a function DoIntersect taking two rectangles and telling you if they intersect.

There are MANY improvements that could be made to this if it is not effecient enough for your needs. you could potentially sort based on coordinates and be able to eliminate a lot of comparisons. But, that all depends on what your data looks like and how fast this needs to be.

If you want to have the output contain each of the original IEnumerable along with a status about whether is intersects any others than switch to using a Select() as below.

```
var allWithIntersectionStatus = rectangles.Select(rect => new
{
    Value = rect,
    DoesIntersect = rectangles
        .Where(rectWhere => rectWhere != rect)
        .Any(rectAnt => DoIntersect(rect, rectAnt))
});
```

Comment: as far as i understand the code, this will output all intersecting rectangles, but what i am looking for is a sequence of boolean values with the same count as the reactangles. but i guess this would be possible by replacing the first Where with a Select, right?

Comment: @thalm see 2nd example in answer.

Comment: yes, this is as close as you can get, it does not consider double checks for AB and BA but its simple and the Any stops as soon as it finds a true value. its good enough for my purposes. thanks!